# How to: Add TextOverflow.ellipsis to Text without specifying maxLines? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I basically want to show a TextOverflow.ellipsis when my Text wraps and overflows at the bottom of a Column.

If I don't specify maxLines, then the ellipsis begins when the Text reaches the edge of the Column (the max width).

If I do specify maxLines then the ellipsis is visible but only if text fits in the space .. this could be a problem on smaller screens and also will begin the ellipsis before the bottom of the Column on larger screens.

Is this even possible? Seems like it should be :/